# PHP: Incomplete differences between the numbers of an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, difference, subtraction

I have created the array `$numbers` which consists of 45 numbers sorted from smallest to largest, with no number appearing twice:

```
$numbers = [5, 12, 24, 43, 60, 84, 87, 94, 124, 178, 226, 276, 313, 327, 336, 364, 367 , 368, 383, 399, 403, 434, 505, 539, 545, 582 , 584, 586, 651, 654, 676, 729, 739, 750, 754, 777, 788, 808, 814, 846, 857, 886, 895, 932, 999];
```

I also define the empty array `$differences`:

```
$differences = [];
```

and save the amount of elements in `$numbers` as the variable `$amount`:

```
$amount = count($numbers);
```

My goal is to save all differences between the elements of `$numbers` in the array `$differences` i.e.:

```
$differences[] = $numbers[1] - $numbers[0];
$differences[] = $numbers[2] - $numbers[1];
```

etc.

I would like this process to be done more efficiently through the use of a for loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $amount; $i++) {
       $differences[] = $numbers[$i] - $numbers[$i-1];
    };
```

The loop seems to be working fine, however, looking at the content of `$differences` one notices that it only has 42 numbers stored in it, not the expected 44. By printing `$differences` you can see that it lacks the last two differences.

Since the script seems to be working fine otherwise and the simplicity of the loop does not leave room for many mistakes, I find this malfunction very bizarre.

Does anyone know what the cause of it might be and how it can be fixed?

EDIT: I isolated the part of the script from my question and now it really doesn't show any faults. I presume I made a mistake in some other part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and it outputs 44 results, there's no error here.

```
$numbers = [5, 12, 24, 43, 60, 84, 87, 94, 124, 178, 226, 276, 313, 327, 336, 364, 367 , 368, 383, 399, 403, 434, 505, 539, 545, 582 , 584, 586, 651, 654, 676, 729, 739, 750, 754, 777, 788, 808, 814, 846, 857, 886, 895, 932, 999];
$amount = count($numbers);
for ($i = 1; $i < $amount; $i++) {
  $differences[] = $numbers[$i] - $numbers[$i-1];
};
  var_dump($differences);
```

Result:

```
array(44) {
  [0]=>
  int(7)
  [1]=>
  int(12)
  [2]=>
  int(19)
  [3]=>
  int(17)
  [4]=>
  int(24)
  [5]=>
  int(3)
  [6]=>
  int(7)
  [7]=>
  int(30)
  [8]=>
  int(54)
  [9]=>
  int(48)
  [10]=>
  int(50)
  [11]=>
  int(37)
  [12]=>
  int(14)
  [13]=>
  int(9)
  [14]=>
  int(28)
  [15]=>
  int(3)
  [16]=>
  int(1)
  [17]=>
  int(15)
  [18]=>
  int(16)
  [19]=>
  int(4)
  [20]=>
  int(31)
  [21]=>
  int(71)
  [22]=>
  int(34)
  [23]=>
  int(6)
  [24]=>
  int(37)
  [25]=>
  int(2)
  [26]=>
  int(2)
  [27]=>
  int(65)
  [28]=>
  int(3)
  [29]=>
  int(22)
  [30]=>
  int(53)
  [31]=>
  int(10)
  [32]=>
  int(11)
  [33]=>
  int(4)
  [34]=>
  int(23)
  [35]=>
  int(11)
  [36]=>
  int(20)
  [37]=>
  int(6)
  [38]=>
  int(32)
  [39]=>
  int(11)
  [40]=>
  int(29)
  [41]=>
  int(9)
  [42]=>
  int(37)
  [43]=>
  int(67)
}
```

Comment: I did the same with the same result: prints out 44 entries. @Andrey Samarskiy the code you use seems to be slightly different?

Comment: I isolated the part of the script from my question and now it really doesn't show any faults. Thank you! I presume I made a mistake in some other part.

Comment: @AndreySamarskiy no problem, good luck with your program. Please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton Please note that "unable to reproduce" is a close vote reason. Questions like these should be closed and not answered.

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks I was unaware of this

Comment: @PatrickQ which option do you select when flagging these?

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton "Off-Topic" -> "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton I'm not sure what options are available at your rep level.  Choose the closest that matches the actual Close Vote option (something indicating that the question is off-topic and/or should be closed).

Comment: @PatrickQ don't worry your original method under "off-topic" works fine for me. Thank you